# What changes does advancing to a new era have?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Judging from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68334/is-there-drawbacks-to-rushing-an-era), advancing to a new era *may* have this effects:

> - increased bonuses more from city-states
> - unlocks policies
> - makes your opponents think your are ahead in tech (at least in multiplayer)
> - cities make more damages (or is it just the animation that changes ?)

But is that all (or true, at least)? I've heard in some "Let's Play" I was watching that changing era decreses the costs of past era technologies. Is that actually true?

There is a comprehensive list of changes you get by advancing to a new era?

Comment: Additional changes include adding spies to your civilization and potentially increasing the level of the World Congress (which needs half of all the civilizations to reach the new era, if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 4):

The following things change when you switch eras

- Potential new spy
- city state bonuses increases
- internal trade routes improve
- religious purchases increase in price
- policy trees unlock
- potentially unlocks ideologies
- As poland, gain a new policy
- affects world congress/UN voting system by making citystates worth
  more.
- makes it more expensive to buy influence with citystates

I do not believe that changing eras decreases the beaker cost of scientific research from before that era.